# How does the arp command resolve hostnames?

Tags: networking, ethernet

When I run the arp command I get the following:

```
mark@mark-P8Z77-I-0:~$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.128            ether   08:86:3b:c8:d8:09   C                     eth0
192.168.1.4              ether   e0:91:f5:7c:7c:34   C                     eth0
192.168.1.110            ether   9c:d3:6d:b1:d3:49   C                     eth0
192.168.1.101            ether   94:10:3e:48:60:0d   C                     eth0
mark-N3050T              ether   d0:17:c2:ad:ff:58   C                     eth0
192.168.1.117            ether   b8:27:eb:ad:2e:72   C                     eth0
192.168.1.129                    (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.103            ether   ec:1a:59:cb:42:25   C                     eth0
192.168.1.111            ether   54:4a:16:02:54:a8   C                     eth0
192.168.1.127            ether   84:ba:3b:05:6d:45   C                     eth0
192.168.1.106            ether   a4:77:33:2b:29:40   C                     eth0
192.168.1.122            ether   00:18:dd:04:6a:cc   C                     eth0
mark-N53Jf               ether   48:5d:60:71:7f:be   C                     eth0
gateway                  ether   28:c6:8e:20:a8:e5   C                     eth0
```

All three hostnames that are present in the report can also be pinged using `ping hostname`
The arp table, /proc/net/arp contains only ip addresses:

```
mark@mark-P8Z77-I-0:~$ cat /proc/net/arp
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.1.128    0x1         0x2         08:86:3b:c8:d8:09     *        eth0
192.168.1.4      0x1         0x2         e0:91:f5:7c:7c:34     *        eth0
192.168.1.110    0x1         0x2         9c:d3:6d:b1:d3:49     *        eth0
192.168.1.101    0x1         0x2         94:10:3e:48:60:0d     *        eth0
192.168.1.138    0x1         0x2         d0:17:c2:ad:ff:58     *        eth0
192.168.1.117    0x1         0x2         b8:27:eb:ad:2e:72     *        eth0
192.168.1.129    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.1.103    0x1         0x2         ec:1a:59:cb:42:25     *        eth0
192.168.1.111    0x1         0x2         54:4a:16:02:54:a8     *        eth0
192.168.1.127    0x1         0x2         84:ba:3b:05:6d:45     *        eth0
192.168.1.106    0x1         0x2         a4:77:33:2b:29:40     *        eth0
192.168.1.122    0x1         0x2         00:18:dd:04:6a:cc     *        eth0
192.168.1.121    0x1         0x2         48:5d:60:71:7f:be     *        eth0
192.168.1.1      0x1         0x2         28:c6:8e:20:a8:e5     *        eth0
```

What service does the arp command and ping use to resolve the hostname?

I have tried several but the closest I get is avahi-browse.  However it reports more hostnames on my network than arp reports and all have `.local` appended to the name.

Also two of the three hostnames that arp reports are remote ubuntu systems.  I do not recall performing any special configuration on those systems to permit this behavior.  The "gateway" hostname is provided by the router.  One of the connected systems is a raspian system.

How would I configure the raspian for this behavior?
How are the hostnames transferred?

What command would I use to resolve these hostnames?

A final note:  The hostnames seem to come and go based on how stale the data is but I have not fully investigated this.  I only know that I need to ping from a given (ubuntu) host for it to capture hostnames of other systems.  I have not scoped out what queries most rapidly fill this information.

After reviewing the comments as of 8:00PM EST Dec. 18. I can share the following information:
The hosts line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns mdns4 myhostname
```

no remote hosts are listed in `/etc/hosts`

`avahi-resolve-address` resolves the following:

```
192.168.1.1    Failed to resolve: Timeout reached (is "gateway")
192.168.1.117 raspberrypi.local    (shows in arp report as 192.168.1.117)
192.168.1.138 mark-3050T.local    (shows in arp as mark-3050T)
192.168.1.130 is currently offline but is similar to 192.168.1.130
```

Though mark-N3050T is reported by arp, pinging it fails.
`ping mark-N3050T.local` fails but `ping 192.168.1.138` succeeds
ping gateway succeeds.
`ping raspberrypi.local` succeeds even though raspberrypi is not reported by arp

When I was writing my original post `ping mark-N3050T` would work so some ageing is occurring that removes this hostname.  I have not found the command that will refresh the hostname.  The difference between arp and ping is that arp is resolving an IP address to a hostname while ping is performing the opposite.  However, I would expect symmetry in the answers.

I am only pursuing this to increase my understanding of how LAN networking works.  I do appreciate anyone who is willing to assist me.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the sequence:

- At first `arp` gets it's data (cache) from `/proc/net/arp`, Linux exposes it's ARP cache via the psuedo `procfs` filesystem's `/proc/net/arp` file for the userland. The kernel does not store any domain name, only IP addresses; this is analogous to using `arp -n`
- Now when you want `arp` to get you the hostnames, `arp` will simply follow the `glibc`'s `nsswitch` configuration, precisely `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and will try to get you the hostnames using the very sequence mentioned in that file e.g. an example is `hosts: files mdns4 dns`, in this case `arp` will:

  - Check the `/etc/hosts` file
  - Then `mdns` (Multicast DNS)
  - General DNS

  Just to note, if you see `.local` at the end of a domain name, then it's (presumably) resolved by `mdns` (unless you actually have such a TLD).

Comment: Thanks.  You describe what I largely suspected.  However, I cannot seem to find commands that return the same information that arp returns.  For example, on my main machine I can ping "mark-N3050T", "mark-N53Jf", and "gateway".  I can also ping "raspberrypi.local" but not "raspberrypi", neither hostname being returned by arp.  If i use avahi-browse to see what information mndns4-minimum might use I see .local for mark-N3050T, mark-N53Jf and raspberrypi.  I do not see anything for gateway.  I probably need to sniff my network more carefully to see how the hostnames are being exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

address resolution protocol (ARP) broadcasts an ARP request packet to all hosts on the network saying

```
Source=MAC-ADDRESS B
Destination=????    
who-has IP A Tell IP B
```

where IP A is the ip your looking for and IP B is your IP Address, if the receving computer's ip address matches it sends a unicast ARP reply back to your computer with

```
Source=MAC-ADDRESS A
Destination=MAC-ADDRESS B    
IP A is-at MAC-Address A
```

and thats all arp dose